Unable to initialize gtk+, is DISPLAY set properly
error:- The exe is made on wxWidget & use for only input/output purpose, but it shows an error on virtual terminal or server: Unable to initialize gtk+, is DISPLAY set properly? I'm super worried. What should I do or change in my code to get rid of it.


Is this Ubuntu Server, or a desktop version?

So you have written a wxWindows application that doesn't actually instantiate any windows, and you want to run it in a CLI? This old thread run wxWidgets GUI application in console hints it may be possible by overloading wxInitialize - otherwise, you may have to resort to providing a dummy display (perhaps using xvfb). See also Is it possible to run unit tests with wxWidgets with just the console and no UI?
